# How to deploy fuse project in server?

Tags: maven, apache-camel, osgi-bundle, jbossfuse, fabric8

I create one fuse project using Jboss developer studio with apache camel spring context..

Currently I am running my project in local machine in internal Jboss-eap of Jboss developer studio. Now i want to deploy my project in application server or container.

Please give me answer of below question :

---

1) What should i use : fabric8 or osgi?

2) What are the dependency need to add in pom.xml for deployment?

3) I have jboss-fuse-6.1.0.redhat-379 , as per my understanding it is container. For deploy my project in server should i required any application server like jboss-eap?

4) As i am using maven for dependency, should i need to copy my maven local repository to server?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to read the JBoss Fuse 6.1 documentation - there is a deploying into the container guide

- https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.1/html/Deploying_into_the_Container/

As you have JBoss Fuse then its a container by itself, so you do not need JBoss EAP - its two different containers.

You can deploy from the Eclipse editor if you have the Fuse plugins installed (I think they are named integration stack). You can read how to install those plugins at the installation section from this page: http://tools.jboss.org/blog/

Comment: Hi Claus, I am able to deploy my blueprint project into my local jboss fuse using fabric8:deploy command.... Now my question is how to deploy my bundle into server (remote server)?.. i already install jboss fuse into remote server..